# Problems running my app, java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: android, kotlin, runtimeexception

today I have tried running my app, but and have a problem, that i don't know it is. Yesterday worked correctly.

If I comment the indicated line the application runs perfectly

Thanks for your help.

This is the error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tribuum_app_2022, PID: 7542
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tribuum_app_2022/com.example.tribuum_app_2022.ui.view.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)

at android.app.ActivityThread.- wrap12(ActivityThread.java)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.tribuum_app_2022.ui.view.MainActivity.validateUserLogin(MainActivity.kt:37)
at com.example.tribuum_app_2022.ui.view.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:30)

at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)

at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)

at android.app.ActivityThread.- wrap12(ActivityThread.java)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

The line where the mistake exist

```
private fun validateUserLogin(){
        val guardarEnXml = getSharedPreferences("datos_usuario_login", MODE_PRIVATE)
        txtUserLoginIdShare = guardarEnXml.getString("id", null)
        txtUserLoginPassShare = guardarEnXml.getString("pass", null)
Line 37: userLogin = UserLogin(txtUserLoginIdShare!!,txtUserLoginPassShare!!)
        userViewModel.loginUser(userLogin)
    }
```

The class of the object:

```
package com.example.app_2022.domain.model
import com.example.app_2022.data.model.UserLoginModel

data class UserLogin(var id: String?, var pass: String?)
fun UserLoginModel.toDomain() = UserLogin(id,pass)
```

The other class that change the type of the object:

```
package com.example.app_2022.data.model
import com.example.app_2022.domain.model.UserLogin
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class UserLoginModel(
    @SerializedName("idUsuario") var id: String?,
    @SerializedName("contrasena") val pass: String?
)

fun UserLogin.toDatabase() = UserLoginModel(id = id, pass = pass)
```

Comment: Try to clean project/Delete build folder and run again.

Answer (score 1):

The logcat is saying there is a `NullPointerException` in line 37. So there `txtUserLoginIdShare` and `txtUserLoginPassShare` can be null.
Because all the values from `SharedPreferences` can be null. So you should check it before use, instead of forcing it to `NotNull` by using `!!`.

Comment: Either that or provide a default value (like `""`) instead of `null` when retrieving it.